# Error when adding more than one app module

Tags: angularjs

I am using two app modules in this app. Why do I get this error? I define the navCtrl in my index.html file where ng-view is like this:

```
<body ng-app="ciscoImaDashboardApp" ng-controller="navCtrl">

Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'navCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I getting this because I define angular.module in all my js files?

Routes JS:

```
angular.module('ciscoImaDashboardApp', ['ciscoImaDashboardAdmin', 'ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/admin', {
    templateUrl: 'views/admin.html'
  })
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/welcome.html',
    controller: 'welcomeCtrl'
  })
  .when('/overall-results', {
    templateUrl: 'views/overall.html',
    controller: 'overallCtrl'
  })
  .when('/swim-lane-results', {
    templateUrl: 'views/swim-lane.html',
    controller: 'swimlaneCtrl'
  })
  .when('/key-exemplifiers', {
    templateUrl: 'views/key-exemplifiers.html',
    controller: 'petalCtrl'
  })
});
```

Second Module:

```
angular.module('ciscoImaDashboardAdmin',[])
.controller('minisCtrl', function ($scope) {
});
```

Nav JS:

```
angular.module('ciscoImaDashboardApp',['ciscoImaDashboardAdmin'])
.controller('navCtrl', function($scope, navService, $location, dummyData) {
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right way :

```
angular.module('ciscoImaDashboarAdmin')
.controller('minisCtrl', function ($scope) {
});
```

remove dependency practice in the second time

Comment: plz mention ur angularjs version !!

Comment: also no need to inject "ciscoImaDashboardAdmin" again in Nav js , its already there from the first injection

Comment: angular.module('ciscoImaDashboardApp')
.controller('navCtrl', function($scope, navService, $location, dummyData) {
});

Comment: Thanks Hasan! Works now

Answer (score 0):

from angular js documentation you can find below block check the link [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)

> Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using angular.bootstrap instead. AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other.