# Is it possible to have two app in one html

Tags: angularjs

This is my code.

```
<body ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-app='myApp1'>

    </div>
</body>
```

And this is my js file.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngAnimate','ngTouch']);
app.controller('mainctrl', ...)

var app1= angular.module('myApp1', []);
```

Is it possible? Could work properly?

Comment: yes you can have it... but they should not be nested..as single application will have separate `root` element

Comment: Is there a reason why myApp1 cannot be a submodule of myApp: `angular.module('myApp', ['myApp1'])` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when adding more than one app module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34481574/error-when-adding-more-than-one-app-module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this,

```
<body>
<div ng-app='myApp'></div>
<div ng-app='myApp1'></div>
</body>
```

they can't be nested

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple app in your code but cannot nest app inside app. But need to separate them like:

```
<body>
<div ng-app='myApp'>
</div>
<div ng-app='myApp1'>
</div>
</body>
```

You can check the [docs note](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)

There are a few things to keep in mind when using ngApp:

1. only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using angular.bootstrap instead.
2. **AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other.**
3. Do not use a directive that uses transclusion on the same element as ngApp. This includes directives such as ngIf, ngInclude and ngView. Doing this misplaces the app $rootElement and the app's injector, causing animations to stop working and making the injector inaccessible from outside the app.

If you need to work with myApp1 code inside myApp then you need to integrate it into the parent one as dependency.

```
var app1= angular.module('myApp1', ['myApp']);
```

Look for this in [dependency injection guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify any nested apps in the module def of the main one.

```
angular.module("myApp", ['statusapp', 'myApp1']).controller(....
```

and in a separate file, you have the other apps defined. We're using a template engine which hides some of this, but you'll end up with HTML that contains nested ng-apps and javascript for each one that defines the module/controller. The code above is the trick to getting more than one bootstrapped.

Answer (score 0):

According to official [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp):

> Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML
>   document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define
>   the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple
>   applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them
>   using angular.bootstrap instead.
>
> AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other.

I think this should answer your question.